# No feedback after data insertion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I want to print out something with my ajax after node.js has finished inserting records to my db. like "console.log('it working')" but unfortunately ajax cannot print out after nodejs has finished inserting the records.

**ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#new-user-form").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = {};
        data.title  = $('#title').val();
        data.fname  = $('#fname').val();
        data.mname  = $('#mname').val();
        data.lname  = $('#lname').val();
        data.mdname = $('#mdname').val();
        $('#loading').show();
        //toastr.success('Page Loaded!');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/new-user",
            type: "POST",            
            data: data,
            dataType: 'application/json',
            cache: false,        
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('it working');
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
        });
    }));
});
```

**new-user.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
router  = express.Router(),
db      = require('./../db');

router.post('/', function (req,res,next) {
  var title       = req.body.title;
  var first_name  = req.body.fname;
  var middle_name = req.body.mname;
  var last_name   = req.body.lname;
  var maiden_name = req.body.mdname;
  var sql = db.insert({first_name:first_name,last_name:last_name}).into('users').then(function(data){
    res.send(data);
  });
if(sql){
  console.log('records inserted');
   }else{
    console.log('insertion failed');
   }
});
```

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network for clues. Not clear if `db.insert()` is even working or not and you don't send anything if it doesn't

Comment: I use the dev tools but nothing shows. I use if function to check if insertion is ok. db.insert() works fine

Comment: Not possible for nothing to show in network if the insert is being made unless the actual form is being submitted by browser default provess and page reloads

Comment: I have updated my code

Comment: But no mention of details per comment above

Comment: If the insertion is OK, I only get the message from the server side console not the browser side. This is the message i get "POST /new-user 200"

Comment: Have you even inspected the actual request in browser dev tools network? That is the important starting point. Again...is page reloading?

Comment: Am using ajax so the page does not reload after hitting the submit button

Comment: Ok.. so what does inspecting the request tell you?

Comment: At the network side of inspecting I get "Status 200 OK" when I submit the form.

Comment: `dataType:` is invalid value. Also add an error handler for `$.ajax`. If you want json need to set it properly and also return json from server

Comment: its works now after I changed the 'dataType:'. Thank you very much